# Converting VMWare to ISO

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player, virtualization, disk-image

I installed VMWare player on vista and tried Ubuntu on it, I am quite happy with it, the built my dev env on it (Ruby, Rails, MySQL etc). Now i want to move to a dedicated machine, is it possible to create a iso file out from VMWare file, so that i can use the same to install? Or is some command available in Ubuntu for same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*is it possible to create a iso file out from VMWare file, so that i can use the same to install?*

Not quite.  The basic premise is that you boot the virtual machine up with some disk imaging tool, image your disk, then deploy the image to  the physical machine & deal with the driver issues.

[VMWare has a detailed](http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/doc/V2P_TechNote.pdf) document on how to do it.